# Loading nested csv files from S3 with Spark

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-csv

I have hundreds of gzipped csv files in s3 that I am trying to load. The directory structure resembles the following:

```
bucket
-- level1
---- level2.1
-------- level3.1
------------ many files 
-------- level3.2
------------ many files 
---- level2.2
-------- level3.1
------------ many files 
-------- level3.2
------------ many files
```

There may be several level2, level3 directories and many files under each. In the past I was loading the data using .textFile and passing the path using a wildcard like:

```
s3a://bucketname/level1/**
```

which worked fine to load all the files under all child paths. I am now trying to use the csv loading mechanism in spark 2 and I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.stringToPath(StringUtils.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:377)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(SparkContext.scala:1014)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(SparkContext.scala:1014)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:179)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
```

I have tried using the following paths:

1. s3a://bucketname/level1/**
2. s3a://bucketname/level1/
3. s3a://bucketname/level1

All result in the same error. If I use **s3a://bucketname/level1/level2.1/level3.1/** that works to load all the files under that one directory but if I try to use a higher level directory it fails.

My code to load is:

```
   Dataset<Row> csv = sparkSession.read()
            .option("delimiter", parseSettings.getDelimiter().toString())
            .option("quote", parseSettings.getQuote())
            .csv(path);
```

I though the csv loading used sparks normal file resolution strategy but the behavior seems to be different from using textFile, is there a way to achieve the loading of all the files with the csv format?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Same problem: "Can not create a Path from an empty string"

Answer (score 0):

sounds suspiciously like a bug.

That means: search for the error message and stack trace in issue.apache.org. FWIW, it could be [SPARK-15473](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15473). If it's there & not yet, add to it with your stack; if not there add something new.

first: isolate it from s3 input; try to replicate it with file:// URLs. That'll help point the blame at the right piece of code.

Also, workaround time. The databricks CSV reader still works

Comment: Running the code locally going against my local filesystem using file:// works correctly.  I will take a look at the jira item.